# AJAX problem in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have made an AJAX chatroom; and it works in chrome and FF, but of course, not in IE. Here's my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest; 
    try {
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
         try {
           ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e){
           alert("Your browser broke!");
           return false;
     }
  }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "pull.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);  
}

setInterval( "ajaxFunction()", 1000 );

//-->
</script>
```

The result never displays. I have a div named AjaxDiv if that helps anyone. What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: Or you could use jquery/mootools, which'd reduce all that to about 2 lines. Rolling your own ajax handlers these days is too painful.

Comment: ive considered that option, but im more concerned if microsoft made a bug in such a widely-used product

Comment: That code actually looks fine to me.  Odd.  Especially since IE9 is by default strict standards mode and is relatively compliant.  XMLHTTPRequest should already work fine.

Comment: @Ken http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Check_Your_Code_First_before_Looking_to_Blame_Others

Comment: Check your DOM manipulation code, or other code.  Also, alert or console.log your "responseText" so you are sure it's ajax that is acting up.

Comment: @phihag if it worked in IE8, then why shouldnt it work in IE9? Are you saying I'm jumping the gun? I've been trying to get this for a week!

Comment: @Ken IE9 is standards mode by default and more standards compliant than earlier browsers.  I have found that this compliance has broken a lot of old code that uses kludges or assumed incorrect behavior.  So, he has a point.

Comment: @Ken Can you provide a full working example? I copied your code and it works fine in IE9 (Windows7 x86): http://phihag.de/2011/so/ie9-ajax.html . And IE8 had quite a share of bugs, you may inadvertently send buggy IE8 code to IE9 too.

Comment: Post an example to http://jsfiddle.net  jsfiddle is your friend

Comment: When dealing with Ajax, also load the php ypu are calling into your browser to see if the file you load actually loads. Perhaps IE9 tightened what it wants to see in XML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably yanking out a cached copy every time you make a request.

Either set the correct caching headers on the server

```
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
```

Or append a query string to the get request like the following

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "pull.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Adding the headers to my script worked a treat. Still an annoying feature of IE9 though!

Comment: @epascarello Do I need to add those headers to the top of all the php scripts I am sending ajax requests to? Basically just copy and paste what you put there to the top of my ajax scripts? firebug claims that my Cache-Control is no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, and my pragma is no-cache. But I don't have those headers at the top of the script I'm posting to, and I didn't see anything in phpinfo.php that says my server is sending those headers with everything. I'm using jquery to do the ajax, and I get this error intermittently.