# jQuery $.ajax not submitting data

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm having a very weird jQuery AJAX problem that I can't figure out.

The problem is that in IE9, only sometimes (I can't reproduce it), it doesn't submit any data, although the AJAX returns successfully. As well, 1 AJAX POST will not send any data while the next one and any following on the same page will be successful.

The AJAX runs in the game on Big Shrimp Contest here: [www.bigshrimpcontest.com/play](http://www.bigshrimpcontest.com/play)

There are a few AJAX POSTs that happen during the game: (1) at the start (recording a start time), (2) when the game ends (recording the end time and stats/score from the game), (3) when the entry form is submitted (recording their name, email, etc). On the server, I'll see the request, but there is no POST or GET data. I've only seen the problem in IE9 (we've blocked IE6 & 7).

The game JavaScript is here: [www.bigshrimpcontest.com/js/game.js](http://www.bigshrimpcontest.com/js/game.js) The AJAX requests are line 258 (#1), line 40 (#2), line 99 (#3).

I've tried setting the cache to false, but that didn't make any difference. I was using jQuery Form, but I've removed it and the problem is persisting.

Any ideas? I'm willing to try things as long as they don't break the game.

I'm also concerned that I use the same methods on other projects that are much more important to save the data.

**Edit**

I've tried both of these options: adding a timestamp and changing the user-agent meta tag to IE8 and EmulateIE8, both with no luck.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's a jQuery's fault. I guess you should wait for the new version that fixes the problem - and in the meanwile you can add "EmulateIE8" to your meta-tags.

Comment: I've changed the meta tag to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;chrome=1"> and still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

Comment: Instead of $.ajax you could try using $.get with predefined parameters, there is small chance of succeeding though. I can't think of anything else - good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

> it doesn't submit any data, although the AJAX returns successfully.

It sounded like caching problem to me. According to jQuery cache:

> cacheBoolean Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

However, I probe the URL through FF Firebug, I didn't the additional "_=[TIMESTAMP]" being appended to your URL.

Check the accepted answer in this [SO Question ajax-problem-in-ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996702/ajax-problem-in-ie9) and try appending the Timestamp manually instead through setting cache to false in jQuery.

Comment: I tried adding a separate ts var in the POST data, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I've found a solution: use GET (vs POST). I changed all of my requests to to `$.ajax('...', { type : 'GET' ... });` and since then there have been no problems. I also had to shorten the variables so that the GET request wouldn't be too long for IE. This may have also been part of the solution, but I don't know for sure.